# Simple Value Converter not working in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters

My WrapPanel is placed inside a grid's * sized cell. Now I have a viewbox placed inside of this WrapPanel.I want to divide the height of the WrapPanel by 3 and then bind it to the ViewBox. So I have tried to use converter. But still I am not getting any changes to the height or the width of ViewBox.

Here is my code:

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="wpTilesContainer">
    <Viewbox x:Name="viewbox1"
        Width="{Binding Width, Converter={StaticResource TilesHeightAndWidthConverter}, ElementName=wpTilesContainer}"
        Height="{Binding Height, Converter={StaticResource TilesHeightAndWidthConverter}, ElementName=wpTilesContainer}">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill="DodgerBlue" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=viewbox1}" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=viewbox1}"  />
            <TextBlock Text="HAEMOGRAM REPORT" FontSize="32" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</WrapPanel>
```

Here is the code for Converter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Lab_Lite.Converter
{
    class TilesHeightAndWidthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double result;
            result = (double)value / (double)3;
            return result;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do people always try to bind the size of a child element to the size of the parent, or some fraction of it? This is hardly ever necessary. Instead, use an appropriate layout container, e.g. another Grid, for that purpose. That said, if you want to use a width or height as source of a binding, you should always use `ActualWidth` or `ActualHeight`.

Comment: But the number of viewbox elements is not fixed here.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Consider using a UniformGrid. Honestly, I can hardly think of any layout that can't be done with WPF's panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind it to `ActualHeight`/`ActualWidth` insted of `Height`/`Width`. Here is the code:

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="wpTilesContainer">
<Viewbox x:Name="viewbox1"
    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource TilesHeightAndWidthConverter}, ElementName=wpTilesContainer}"
    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource TilesHeightAndWidthConverter}, ElementName=wpTilesContainer}">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="DodgerBlue" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=viewbox1}" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=viewbox1}"  />
        <TextBlock Text="HAEMOGRAM REPORT" FontSize="32" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: @Khushi glad to be useful

Comment: I have got a problem now, When I restore/maximize window repeatedly, the size of viewbox increases always.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not permitted to share the project. And I have got a good solution from Clemens to use a Uniform Grid.